# Is the reason of not omitting 'to' because of ing?

Tags: infinitives

> All Harry could think of doing was **to** keep Quirrell talking and stop him from concentrating on the mirror.
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

In a different phrase containing *all* and *do*, I see the infinitive complement starts without *to*. Is it the same when *do* is replaced from *doing*, or is the infinite marker required in the latter case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explicit **to** marking the infinitive is actually somewhat "optional", though idiomatically it would probably be used more often than not in OP's exact context.

But there's no grammatical reason why *All Harry could think of doing* is any different to, for example,...

> [*all I can do* is watch](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20little%20guy%20who%20has%20been%20righting%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=45d85324a3c260ea&q=%22all%20I%20can%20do%20is%20watch%22&tbm=bks) (5690 hits in Google Books)
>    [*all I can do* is **to** watch](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20little%20guy%20who%20has%20been%20righting%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=45d85324a3c260ea&q=%22all%20I%20can%20do%20is%20to%20watch%22&tbm=bks) (3940 hits)

Not only could the **to** reasonably be omited in OP's case - it could be recast as

> All Harry [could think **to** do was](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20little%20guy%20who%20has%20been%20righting%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=45d85324a3c260ea&q=%22all%20I%20could%20think%20to%20do%20was%22&tbm=bks) [to] keep Quirrell talking.

---

As regards *...and stop him...*, it's just a stylistic choice to discard the optional **to** the second time. But I must admit it would be *very* unusual (and perhaps "ungrammatical") to use it *only* for the second verb. Besides, in this exact context, that **and** could probably be replaced by **in order to**, so *stopping Quirrell concentrating* doesn't quite have the same relationship to Harry's thinking as *keeping Quirrel talking*.

Comment: Strange!  Counting the results on your second link, I only get 26 results (click through to page three and the number drops from 3940 to 26), and discarding duplicates I only see about 15. Doing the same with the first link, I find an order of magnitude more results.  That's more in line with my expectations, but I'm not sure how reliable this data is...  [GloWbE](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/) gives 14 and 0 results respectively, for what it's worth.

Comment: @snailboat: You're quite right. I thought the figures for that **to** were surprisingly high, but I didn't bother to check in detail. It doesn't really affect my substantive point though - it *does* occur, and I don't see it as "grammatically incorrect". It's just less common to include **to** in my ***exact*** example (but I'd be prepared to bet the idiomatic preference is precisely opposite for OP's exact example).